# How to set disabled input and select to be of same color

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing difficulties to set the same text color for disabled `input` and `select` elements.

*Example:*

```css
input:disabled,
select:disabled,
option:disabled {
  color: #b8b8b8;
}
```

```html
<select disabled style="width: 50pt;">
  <option>123</option>
</select><br>
<input disabled value="123" style="width: 45pt;">
```

[image: different text color]

---

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzghn8xr/1) ...

How can be this fixed to get the same look, the same color being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Opacity:1`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/hcmregvd/3/) to playaround.

```css
input:disabled,
select:disabled,
option:disabled {
  color: #b8b8b8;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<select disabled style="width: 50pt;">
  <option>123</option>
</select><br>
<input disabled value="123" style="width: 45pt;">
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you use the attribute disable, the css property `opacity: 0.7` is getting added to the styling.
Do the same with the input field also or You can override the css property of `select` tag with `opacity:1 !important`
to get the same styling for both the elements

```
input:disabled, select:disabled, option:disabled {
  color: #b8b8b8;
  opacity: 0.7;

}
```